# Flatlist navigation to another screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

So, i've one Flatlist that renders a list of movies, and I'm trying to when I click on it, moves me to a detail page, but it's not working.

Literally, nothing happens and doesn't get any errors on console

My FlatList:

```
<FlatList
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      horizontal
      data={movies}
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
    />
```

My "renderitem" from flatlist:

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
<RenderList url={item.poster_path} title={item.original_title} />
```

);

and that is the RenderList component who fits into the const "renderItem":

```
<View style={styles.view}>
  <Image
    style={{ width: 150, height: 220 }}
    source={{ uri: 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/' + props.url }}
  />
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call `onPress` from a `TouchableOpacity` that loops for each item.

```
<FlatList
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  horizontal
  data={movies}
  onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
  renderItem={({ item }) => {
     return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}>
          <RenderList url={item.poster_path} title={item.original_title} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
     );
   }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the `onPress` on each of the list item, not on the `Flatlist`

```js
<FlatList
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  horizontal
  data={movies}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
/>
```

```js
const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
   return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}>
        <RenderList url={item.poster_path} title={item.original_title} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
   );
}
```